# Error On Say Function

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm using the **Apple Script Editor** that came with Mac System 7.5.5 and trying to run a simple program:

```
say "Starting to empty the trash."
tell application "Finder"
  empty trash
end tell
say "Finished emptying the trash."
```

But when I click in the run button, I got this:

[Say Error http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/7341/applescripterror.png](http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/7341/applescripterror.png)

I got this code from the book AppleScript Language Guide from Apple, published in 1999.

Comment: That's... a slice of history, there.  Can I ask, how did you end up working with a 13-year-old operating system?

Comment: You're going to have to dig up a 15 year old AppleScript language guide to verify your syntax. It's pretty unlikely that anyone remembers anything about 7.5 off the top of their head.

Comment: @Michael I love old OSs and I'm emulating a IIci **;-)**

Comment: I loved that era.  I knew System 7 better than I knew any other OS, before or after. *sniff*

Comment: I love System 7 and the classic versions of Mac OS and hate Mac OS X!

Comment: 1999 was 5 years after System 7.5's release, so very little in that document is going to help you with regards to the availability and syntax of the various scripting additions.

Comment: But is best than a newer version of the book, that the syntax have changed too much. **;-)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem here is that the `say` command is not supported by the version of Applescript that ships with MacOS 7.5.5.  I'm not sure exactly which version of Applescript that is, but I found [this page in the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/19971120212314/http://www.applescript.apple.com/applescript_overview/system8/OS8_index.html) that refers to Applescript 1.1.2 shipping with MacOS 8.  The docs page that Michael linked to for the `say` command is for Applescript 2.1, so I'm guessing `say` didn't come into being until somewhere in the 8.x or possibly even 9.x era.

Comment: The error is exactly what you get if you replace say with garbage, even on OS X, namely that the first word is interpreted as a new variable, after which quotes don't make sense. Your system doesn't know about say. You can confirm that by looking at the dictionary of the StandardAdditions extension.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the wayback machine. I just found the content of my old blog again. The one my hosting company managed to delete for good :-)

Answer (score 2):

This [1996 AppleScript Scripting 
Additions Guide](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Manuals/software/0305098AASADDGENG.PDF) seems nearly contemporary to System 7.5.5 and does not mention `say`. You might poke around in something like `System:Extensions:Scripting Additions` to see if you can pull up their dictionaries. Probably System 7.5.5 predates `say`.